# Use C#'s fileStream to save file will lose the file's attribute

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, stream, attributes

1.I set the custom properties called 'fileId' for fileA with DSOFile.dll

2.I read fileA's total content by fileStream, then I save the fileStream as fileB

3.check fileB, and I find that the attribute 'fileId' doesn't exist in fileB

so, I find the read->write operation by fileStream will lose the document's attribute. And my question is, how let the file's attribute not lose?

This is my code what I have used:

```
// use FileStream to read file
public static string FileStreamReadFile(string filePath)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[100];
    char[] charData = new char[100];
    FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    //文件指针指向0位置
    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //读入两百个字节
    file.Read(data, 0, (int) file.Length);
    //提取字节数组
    Decoder dec = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    dec.GetChars(data, 0, data.Length, charData, 0);
    return Convert.ToString(charData);
}

// use FileStream to write file
public static void FileStreamWriteFile(string filePath, string str)
{
    byte[] byData;
    char[] charData;
    try
    {
        FileStream nFile = new FileStream(filePath + "love.txt", FileMode.Create);
        //获得字符数组
        charData = str.ToCharArray();
        //初始化字节数组
        byData = new byte[charData.Length];
        //将字符数组转换为正确的字节格式
        Encoder enc = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder();
        enc.GetBytes(charData, 0, charData.Length, byData, 0, true);
        nFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        nFile.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new file (B) from the contents of an existing one (A). Either manually set the custom property on the new file or just copy file A to file B rather than using a FileStream to copy the contents.

Something like

```
using System.IO;
File.Copy(filePathA, filePathB);
```

This should preserve the file attributes.

Comment: Thanks~however I can't creating a new file(B) by copy, because it's in web environment. I upload file(A) to Server, then Server save the file(A)'s stream as file(B)

Answer (score 0):

Like @spodger already said, you are just reading the **Content** of the file and write this to a new file. The **properties** you have set on FileA **won´t be set** to the new created one. I would recommend to prove if a property is set to FileA and if so you can set the same one to FileB.

Comment: Thanks~but I must get FileB's attribute first

Comment: Create a new File with new Operator and set Attribute, after you can copy the Content via readers